# Add aditional HDD to already instaled ubuntu server

Tags: hardware

I have installed Ubuntu server 14.04 on desktop computer with 500GB HDD and i make my file server but i have problem with storage and I need additional HDD to be mounted 2TB HDD  please advice how to make my server to see only one volume instead two HDD.

Comment: I think your question is too general. You need to do some reading, and ask questions as they come up.  We have no idea where you need to start, and it is a lot of instructions to tell you everything. If you truly know nothing about how to do it, and can't understand by reading, then perhaps you need to find someone to help.

Comment: Sorry,  because i have installed owncloud and already have a users and clients now i have 500GB HDD if i install 2TB my server will see two HDD or One and how can i make to see only one volume 2,5TB instead two HDD.

Answer (score 0):

Linux has no real notion of drives; it sees one unified filesystem mounted to the root directory (`/`). An app such as gparted will see drives and partitions, which can be mounted to the existing filesystem somewhere of your choosing.

Partitions, or more precisely, filesystems (which may be the entire drive) can be explicitly mounted to any directory of your choosing that you have permissions to use; to do this, you use the `mount` command, normally using `sudo`, since only root can mount filesystems normally.  They can also be mounted automatically by opening it in Nautilus.

The best way to permanently use a disk is to include mounting instructions in the file `/etc/fstab`.  That is where all the other mounts are, including the root filesystem, the swapdrive, etc.  There is a lot of discussions on how to do this for various situations, and you should search and read some, then perhaps ask questions about specific problems rather than asking for it to be reposted here again.

The end result will look like one big disk, and can be set up in any way you want.  Try experimenting first with the mount command to get it set up, then move on to `/etc/fstab` to avoid mounting it every time you reboot.